# Tensorflow InvalidArgumentError when calling model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to setup a really simple keras model in tensorflow. I have a `X_train` and a `Y_train` numpy.ndarray variables with size of `(846, 30, 373)` and `(846, 1, 1)` respectively.
The model looks as follow:

```
visible = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=np.shape(X_train)[1:3])
hidden = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=32)(visible)
dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(hidden)
model_logic = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=visible, outputs=dense)

model_logic.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss='mae')

model_logic.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=10)
```

The last line produces the following `InvalidArgumentError`:

```
InvalidArgumentError: data[0].shape = [3] does not start with indices[0].shape = [2]
     [[{{node RMSprop/gradients_5/loss_7/dense_8_loss/Mean_grad/DynamicStitch}}]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_16435]
```

I believe I am making confusion and passing inputs (`X_train` and `Y_train`) with a shape that keras is not expecting, but I can't figure out why is it the case. What am I doing incorrectly?

Edit: `model_logic.summary()` prints the following:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_9 (InputLayer)         [(None, 30, 373)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                51968     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 33        
=================================================================
Total params: 52,001
Trainable params: 52,001
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

where the shapes seem to be ok with those of my `X_train` and `Y_train`. Or should the Output Shape of the InputLayer be `(None, 30, 373)` instead of `[(None, 30, 373)]`? And if so, where do the extra `[]` come from?

Comment: I'm sure the data shape doesn't match. You can use `print(model_logic.summary())` to print the model structure.

Comment: @giser_yugang I edited my question including the output of `summary()`

Comment: Obviously the output shape required by the model is `(None, 1)`, but your data shape is `(846, 1, 1)`.

Comment: Ach, that was really dumb of me. I somehow focused only on the input shape completely ignoring to check the output. Sorry and thanks for your hints.